# LightSAML Symfony Bridge Bundle, need some clarity

Tags: php, saml-2.0, symfony-2.8

For a project, I've been playing around with LightSAML core library. https://www.lightsaml.com/LightSAML-Core/ I like the library and the cookbook examples provided here were really useful https://www.lightsaml.com/LightSAML-Core/Cookbook/

Apparently it's possible to create an EntityDescriptor and credentials (cert and private key) and to have those accessible through a service container. https://www.lightsaml.com/LightSAML-Core/Cookbook/How-to-build-own-container/
I don't really understand how to do this myself in my Symfony 2.8.* project so I've taken a look at LightSAML Symfony Bridge Bundle

To me the configuration of this bundle and what the possibilities are, are hidden from me or very cryptic. This is the configuration page https://www.lightsaml.com/Symfony-Bridge/Configuration/

For example:

```
id: own_entity_descriptor_provider_service_id
```

This service, how should it look like exactly to get this bundle working?

Could someone shine a light and make this bundle clear to me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm more experienced with SimpleSAMLphp, not Symfony. And actually I have spent like 30 minutes to figure out what is going on here.

https://www.lightsaml.com/Symfony-Bridge/ says:

> "A Symfony bridge bundle configuring internal profile services, used
>   by other security bundles."

And here you put existing SAML SP/IdP configuration, creating so called "profile":
https://www.lightsaml.com/Symfony-Bridge/Configuration/

I think this has nothing to do with actual SAML code/functionality - it provides a bridge for other Symfony services to interact with it some way.

They have separate bundle to setup SP and to setup IdP.